# NIS client cannot find NIS server (Opensuse)

Tags: virtual-machines, opensuse, nis

I installed NIS server on head node of a virtual cluster(VirtualBox). One of the node (let's say node-1) can find NIS server and work with it, but another node (node-2) just can't find the NIS server in Yast while it can ping and ssh to both head node and node-1. BTW, all the nodes are VMs, head node and node-1 are on the same physical machine, node-2 is on another physical machine.

I set the domain name in **/etc/hosts** and **/etc/yp.conf**, and ypwhich sometimes gives the correct domainname several minutes later complains about "ypwhich: Can't communicate with ypbind", and will back to work after some time. Also tried **rpcinfo -p *hostname*** and it worked as expected.

I almost tried every thing I can find on internet, but seems that not many people had this problem.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by disabling firewall on NIS client side.

Answer (score 0):

```
domainname [domainname]
ypdomainname [domainname]
service ypbind restart
```

What does that give you?

Comment: domainname gives correct domain name, so does ypdomainname, after restart ypbind, Yast still can't find NIS server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the hosts listed in /etc/yp.conf are NIS masters or slaves?  You might want to amend the problem and attach a copy of the /etc/yp.conf file.  Have you checked for a syntax error in this file?

Next, do any of the NIS master or slave server have IP protection via the securenets if I recall the filename?  If so, an administrator will have to change this.

Those are my suggestions of areas.

Comment: Thanks for the answering. The content in /etc/yp.conf looks like  `ypserver 192.168.5.1
domain nis.sirius broadcast
domain nis.sirius.blabla.com broadcast
` which I copied from the node-1 which is working. I only have master, no slave NIS server. ypwhich also gives correct domainname.  I have sudo permission, how should I check if it's the IP protection problem? The Google result for it is not clear.